# ASP.NET MVC Site With ELMAH.MVC - Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

I am creating an MVC4 site using .NET 4.0, IIS 7+.  It is internal so I am using Windows Authentication.  I have decided to use **ELMAH**, and since this is MVC I have decided to use the **Elmah.MVC** NuGet package.

Logging exceptions works.  I have it setup to log to the App_Data folder and to also send emails.  It does both of these things just fine.

But I wanted to use the UI to actually look at all the errors.  So I browse to site.com/elmah and the site pops up with a request for my credentials.  This is confusing to me since it should be using Windows Authentication and I should be on the list of users already.  The rest of my application uses the `HttpContext.Current.User` correctly from the visiting user so I am confused how /elmah is not working correctly.

The site's Application Pool is set to **NetworkService** and the site itself is set to connect using **Pass-through authentication**.

What would I be missing exactly?

Here are my elmah.mvc appSettings:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="DOMAIN\user1,DOMAIN\user2" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
```

Comment: I dropped your configuration into my web.config and my elmah continued to function normally. As an experiment, try setting the elmah.mvc.route to a route you know you can successfully access and see what happens.

Comment: @Grax thx for helping.  I will answer / close my own question.  But I figured out the issue after trying many many things.  It turns out that `elmah.mvc.allowedUsers` is actually case sensitive when it shouldn't be.  I will submit a change to GitHub.  Hopefully that will be merged in at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any one still looking, in the latest elmah nuget package there is a new setting for username case sensitivity.

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I added a PR for this new setting :)  I hope you find it useful.